# Brand new computer froze twice

Tags: ssd, freeze, desktop-computer

I just built a new desktop — here are the components:

- Asus p8z68-v pro gen3
- Intel i7 2600k
- 120 GB OCZ Agility 3
- 16 GB RAM Blue Corsair DDR3
- Asus GTX 570
- H80 Corsair liquid cooling
- xfx PRO750W 80Plus bronze power supply

It froze twice yesterday, the mouse, keyboard, everything. I had to force shutdown.
I did a `memtest86` all night and no error.

The temp was low when it froze. It was exactly 23C, and the cpu was 21C. I was lucky the software for the temp was open when it happened. I wasn't even playing. Only Windows live messenger was open.

Also the video card failed twice last week. The screen went black for 10 seconds then Windows 7 told me that my video card driver failed.

All the drivers are up to date and Windows 7 Premium 64bits also.

Do you think it could be a problem with my ssd and should I worry for my video card
Nothing was in the event log except the forced shutdown.

**EDIT:**

alright now it froze twice again in 5 minutes. I had to reboot both times.
I updated my bios and set the ram back to auto instead of 1600mhz, let's see if it will freeze again.

Comment: Anything in the event logs?  Windows version?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. No error in the event log and it's windows 7 64 bits premium

Comment: Since you got the Z68 (I have the same mobo), try using the integrated graphics card and see if the issue persists.  If not, I think you need a new GPU.  Also, ensure that your computer is stable when running a few passes of Prime95.

Comment: I will try, do i have to unplug the card or I could just plug my screen in the intergrated card?

Comment: First, of course, reseat EVERYTHING, and make sure all connectors are all the way seated.  Very often certain connectors look seated when they're not.

Comment: @Marc I would remove the GPU just to eliminate any possible source of interference, especially if it has to do with the motherboard itself (although this *is* unlikely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instability is a tough issue to track down. You can constantly test hardware, but until the specific conditions that prompt the failure exists, you won't notice anything. The big three causes of instability is:

1. Low quality hardware
2. Faulty hardware
3. Incompatibilities

From the list you gave, everything seemed to be of the highest quality. The only thing that is unknown is the power supply. There are many low end, high wattage power supplies out there that don't work all that well. There are many reviews out there that can help you determine the quality of the hardware.

For faulty hardware and incompatibilities, the only real solution is to swap out components with known working ones. In this case, you might want to find hardware of a different make and model to swap with. You might find that for some reason your combination of hardware causes problems. This is highly unlikely nowadays, but you should search the internet to see if others are having these issues. In most cases, the motherboard combined with the memory or video card would cause a problem.

So I would double check you power supply and then see if there is other hardware you can use. I wouldn't return anything just yet, but I would see if there was another computer with similar hardware I could swap with.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, my power supply is a xfx PRO750W. It's a 80 plus bronze. My dad has the same hardware but with no video card. I'm gonna try.

Comment: So we can probably rule out the power supply. You might start with moving the video card to another system and seeing if the same problems happens. You also might want to check your bios version number. It looks like ASUS released a few BIOS updates to address system stability. You can find the latest on the ASUS website.

Comment: yeah! They just released an update for mine for the system stability. I'm gonna try that. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Barring messages about I/O errors, don't worry about the SSD.  With a new build, I'd be worrying about memory (which you've checked), and overheated components.  In your case, with the GTX 570, I'd definitely be trying to figure out if that card is overheating, because that would explain everything.  Make sure there is space around the card so its fan can keep air moving freely; the more space the better.  If you have other cards installed that you can do without, try running without them and see if the problem persists.  You really don't want to pack components tightly when you have a high-performance graphics card installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The temp was low when it froze. It was exactly 23C, and the cpu was 21C. I was lucky the software for the temp was open when it happened.

Answer (score 1):

For the graphics card issue where the screen goes black for 10 seconds, what kind of card are you using, are you using a beta driver, and are you overclocking it. I had a issue with a gtx 460 where i would constantly get the same issue as you, but i rolled back the driver and it seemed to go away.

Comment: it happened 2 days after i downloaded their last driver and i don't overclock. The only thing I did, is to set the ram at 1600mhz instead of auto which is the frequency they are supposed to be.

Comment: go into device manager and try rolling back the driver, also check out www.overclock.net, it is a forum site that has alot of information about computers in general. You can go to the Nvidia section and post your issue and since the community may be more about hardware they could probably help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Take out all of the components except the bare minimum (if you have built in graphics, rip the graph card out also)

Put in only one DIMM.

Does it freeze? If it does, its the power supply or voltage regulator, if not that one DIMM, or it could be the CPU getting too hot for just a moment. If not start putting in components one at a time.